# Are mosquitoes repelled by high frequency sound?

Tags: entomology

I am totally confused whether ask this question to physics or biology stackexchange.

I downloaded a mobile application which claims to repel mosquitoes. This application basically produces sound from 16kHz to 22kHz (I doubt that it even produces more than 20kHz because we can't hear more than 20kHz naturally).

I totally doubt this application. Do mosquitoes go away in higher frequency of sound?

Comment: Try to ask one question per post. As is often the case with **UPDATE** titles, what follows should be its own question.

Comment: Have you heard of the proposed Bioacoustics Stack Exchange? It seems like you might be a valuable member of that community. Please consider committing to the page so we can get closer to making it to the Beta stage. Cheers!
https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126698/bioacoustics?referrer=YjZmYjUxYzJkNDI1YmY5NDk3NzdhMzViMmZlNzI4ZDdiYTAyMWQxNTM5ZWFiNzRhODNkMmFiMzIxZjI3MmY1N_gFvrICTvBsmYNJ2ptRM6lIZEAV-VGkXtIwNyVDja680

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After seeing your question, I decided to do a bit of research on the topic.

---

## First Source: [EurekAlert!](http://www.eurekalert.org/pub_releases/2007-04/jws-mrt041607.php)

---

http://www.eurekalert.org/pub_releases/2007-04/jws-mrt041607.php

> "Mosquito repellents that emit high-pitched sounds don't prevent
>   bites"

Some key-points from the webpage:

> ---
>
> A Cochrane Systematic Review of the use of electronic mosquito repellents (EMRs) failed to find any evidence that they work.
>
> ---
>
> To test these claims a team of Cochrane Researchers conducted a systematic review looking for trials conducted with EMRs. They located ten field trials that had been carried out in various parts of the world. None of these trials showed any evidence that EMRs work.
>
> ---
>
> All ten studies found that there was no difference in the number of mosquitoes found on the bare body parts of the human participants with or without an EMR

---

## Second Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insect_repellent)

---

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insect_repellent

> These electronic devices have been shown to have no effect as a mosquito repellent by studies done by the EPA and many universities.

---

## Third Source: [CBCnews](http://www.cbc.ca/news/story/2007/04/18/mosquito-repellent.html)

---

http://www.cbc.ca/news/story/2007/04/18/mosquito-repellent.html
Key points from the article:

> "There was no evidence in the field studies to support any repelling effects of EMRs, hence >no evidence to support their promotion or use"
>              
>   -Ahmadali Enayati, researcher

This is a major point as well:

> The study also said that in 12 of the 15 experiments, the landing rates of mosquitoes on subjects was in fact higher than in control groups.

The article also points out that female mosquitoes can't hear very well- Which supports the idea that high-frequency repellents are ineffective; Much more than you probably think. Why? Well, it's pretty simple:

**Female Mosquitoes are the only Gender that Bite**.

---

Overall, when you consider the countless studies and research put in to the effects of high-frequency sounds on mosquitoes, it's pretty obvious that:

## No.

#### High Frequency Sounds do **NOT** repel mosquitoes

---

[image]

Comment: All three sources reference the same study, and it's unfortunate that the details of the study haven't been made available for peer review.

Comment: Ok, so the results *were* published (http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/14651858.CD005434.pub2/full), but access to the article is not provided with the basic Wiley subscription package that (I assume) is available through most universities.

Comment: @DanielStandage http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/14651858.CD005434.pub2/abstract is the abstract where the relevant information is written: "All 10 studies found that there was no difference in the number of mosquitoes caught from the bare body parts of the human participants with or without an EMR".

Comment: The paper is now [available](http://archive.lstmed.ac.uk/977/1/Electronic_mosquito_repellents.pdf) without dealing with a pay-wall.
By the way, [Wiley's website](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/Brand/id-6.html?category=For+Working) has this to say about the publication the paper was published in: "The Cochrane Library is a collection of databases that contain high-quality, independent evidence to inform healthcare decision making. Cochrane Reviews represent the highest level of evidence on which to base clinical treatment decisions. "

Answer (score 2):

> Ultrasound emitting devices are used to repel mosquitoes. We tested
>   the repelling properties of a commercially available ultrasound device
>   in a domestic setting in Gabon. Devices emitting three different block
>   frequencies ranging from 3 to 11 kHz were tested in a paired,
>   cross-over blinded and placebo controlled trial during eighteen nights
>   in nine pairs of houses. A total of 7485 mosquitoes (10% Anopheles,
>   62% Culex, 27% Mansonia and 1% Aedes) were caught, 23 per house per
>   night. There was no significant difference in landing rate between the
>   houses with ultrasound device and the houses with placebo for any
>   species of mosquito. Thus the ultrasound device used was not effective
>   against mosquitoes in this strictly controlled trial.

[Sylla el-H K, Lell B, Kremsner PG. A blinded, controlled trial of an ultrasound device as mosquito repellent. *Wiener Klinische Wochenschrift*. 2000 May;112(10) 448-450. PubMed PMID: 10890136.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10890136)

---

> A bibliographic review about the use of electroacoustic devices with a
>   supposed repellent action on the females of different species of
>   hematophagous mosquitoes  is presented. 15 direct references and 2
>   indirect ones are given, in which it is  concluded that these devices
>   do not protect those who have them from the stings of mosquitoes. The
>   names of 9 of the tested devices as well as of 16 of the main  species
>   of mosquitoes present in the field tests are mentioned. These tests
>   have  been carried out in very different ecological conditions from
>   Alaska to Equatorial Africa. It is also stressed that the high
>   intensity ultrasonic frequencies emitted by these devices produces a
>   potentially harmful effect on man.

Rev Cubana Med Trop. 1998;50(2):89-92.

[[Electronic repellents against mosquitoes: the propaganda and the reality].](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10349423)

[Article in Spanish]

Coro F(1), Suárez S.

Author information: 
(1)Facultad de Biología, Universidad de La Habana, Ciudad de La Habana, Cuba.

PMID: 10349423  [PubMed - indexed for MEDLINE]

Comment: Answers are supposed to be written by yourself and not only consist of a citation.

Comment: @Chris I am not an expert in the field, what do I need to add to an abstract? I think it is self explanatory, doesn't it?